# Debug mode working but Running gave Error Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have decreased my real activity to very fundamental one which causes the error, When I run my code in "run" it says application stopped, but when I run my code in "debug" it is running without error. Couldn't find why ??

**Here is my activity :**

```
public class Settings extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.scroldowndeneme);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewdeneme);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(Settings.this, R.layout.rowwithimage, new String[]{"singlesamplefortry"});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowwithimage, parent, false);
            ImageView as = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.userpictureofrowwithimage);
            as.setImageResource(R.drawable.profilepicturesmall);

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is layout of scroldowndeneme :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listViewdeneme"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is layout of rowwithimage :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dip"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userpictureofrowwithimage"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/company"
                android:text="CoderzHeaven"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:id="@+id/sub"
                android:text="Heaven of all working codes"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no errors in debug mode. How can I obtain error log in "run" mode ?

Comment: when it says application stopped, the status of logcat .

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. I deleted program from phone and reinstalled it and worked..